# Difference between a date and today

Tags: excel, vba

I have dates in column E starting at E3.

In column F, I want the difference in days. F3 = Today-E3, F4 = Today-E4 and so on until the last value in column E.

This is the code:

```
'Calculate Overdue
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If i = 1 Then
        Workbooks(Main).Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value = "Overdue [days]"
    Else
        Workbooks(Main).Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value = _
        Now - Workbooks(Main).Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, lastcolumn - 1).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What does not work?  Where are you getting an error?

Comment: Why VBA? You can just write a formula and drag it down column F.

Comment: @Valsac in case you want to use the VBA option, try the code in answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the VBA solution, the code below will work.
I prefer to use the `DateDiff` Function, in the code below it will return the overdue in "d" (days).

Also, just to be on the safe side (and have a cleaner code) I always define my Sheet objects (it also reduces the possibilities to encounter errors later).

Since you know your dates are in **Column E**, and the result in **Column F**, I already implemented that in the code (can be replaced with `lastcolumn` , but not sure why).

```
Sub Calc_Overdue()
'Calculate Overdue

Dim Sht             As Worksheet
Dim DaysOverdue     As Long
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim i               As Long

Set Sht = Workbooks(Main).Sheets(1)

i = 1
With Sht
    ' find last row in Column E (where the dates are kept)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    ' there is no need to loop through the IF just to copy the header row
    .Cells(1, "F").Value = "Overdue [days]"

    ' start loop from 2nd row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        DaysOverdue = DateDiff("d", Now, .Cells(i, "E").Value)
        .Cells(i, "F").Value = DaysOverdue
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```